# Compress File Using Ionic.ZIP with Progress Bar [Windows Forms]

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, dotnetzip, ionic-zip

I'm preparing an application that creates a zip file for a given directory.

I want the following things to display while creating a zip.

1. Estimated time for completing that zip (Elapsed Time and Time left)
2. The percentage for completion of Zipping

Here is my written code:

[image]

```
    private void CreateZip(string FilePath)
    {
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            zip.AddProgress += Zip_AddProgress;
            zip.SaveProgress += Zip_SaveProgress;
            zip.CompressionMethod = Ionic.Zip.CompressionMethod.Deflate;
            zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;
            zip.UseZip64WhenSaving = Zip64Option.AsNecessary;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilePath))
            {
                zip.AddDirectory(FilePath, new DirectoryInfo(FilePath).Name);
            }
           var d= zip;

            if (File.Exists(txtDest.Text))
            {
                File.Delete(txtDest.Text);
            }
            zip.Save(txtDest.Text);
        }
    }

    private void Zip_SaveProgress(object sender, SaveProgressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.EventType == ZipProgressEventType.Saving_Started)
            lblFileName.Text = "Proccess Started Successfully";

        if (e.EventType == ZipProgressEventType.Saving_AfterSaveTempArchive)
            lblFileName.Text = "Proccess Completed Successfully";


        if (e.BytesTransferred > 0 && e.TotalBytesToTransfer > 0)
        {
            int progress = (int)Math.Floor((decimal)((e.BytesTransferred * 100) / e.TotalBytesToTransfer));
            pbPerFile.Value = progress;
            lblPercentagePerFile.Text = Convert.ToString(progress) + "%";
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

        if (e.EntriesSaved > 0 && e.EntriesTotal > 0)
        {
            int progress = (int)Math.Floor((decimal)((e.EntriesSaved * 100) / e.EntriesTotal));
            pbTotalFile.Value = progress;
            Application.DoEvents();
            lblTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(progress) + "%";           
        }
    }
```

The first progress bar works on the size of the file because of **e.BytesTransferred** and **e.TotalBytesToTransfer** is return size in **Bytes**.

But **e.EntriesSaved** and **e.EntriesTotal** will return the length of the saved entries and total number of entries that we have added.

So I want that second Progress Bar to work based on the size of the Entire   Selected files and Compressed File.

Your efforts will be appreciated.

Thanks...

Comment: Do you mean that e.EntriesSaved and e.EntriesTotal report the number of files processed and total, respectively? If so, you'll just want to compute the total number of bytes in the input files (use `FileInfo` for that) and keep the total number of bytes processed from already processed files.

Comment: Thanks, @mostanes but it not feasible for me, because I try to add multiple folders so I need to calculate the length of all files in bytes.